# FIrebase Cloud Messaging in React Native [Android]

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to integrate Push Notification in my React Native App so i chose [this](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) and followed all steps including creating google-service.json file and i was receiving notification for about two days and back-end server was using the Firebase SDK to send notification message to Firebase server and the server was sending to all mobile clients but suddenly the notification is stopped receiving from what i can see the back-end log i am receiving status 200 from Firebase server that notification payload is sent from my server to Firebase but the Firebase is not sending the message to the devices i tried to generate test notification from cloud messaging in Firebase still im not able to receive i tried many ways but no success.

is there some quota limit on Firebase cloud messaging? any help or link is highly appreciated and Will be happy to provide more details if required.

```
PushNotification.configure({
 // (optional) Called when Token is generated (iOS and Android)
 onRegister: function (token) {
  console.log("TOKEN:", token);
 })}
```

Even when i tried to send using token id to cloud messaging still im not receiving notification.

[image: From here i send a test message]

Comment: No, there is no quota as such in `firebase`. Firebase is entirely free when it comes to the notification. are you sure that the device ID you registered with is actually correct? if not try generating new device IDs and trigger notifications

Comment: @senthilbalaji for your reference edited the question.